# LinkedIn API get /v2/me returns "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER"

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, python-requests, linkedin-api

## The Problem

I'm trying to run the [requests-OAuth2 LinkedIn](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/master/docs/examples/linkedin.rst) example. I've been able to fix a few issues with the example being out of date but cannot seem to get the last line to run correctly.
The response object contents from running the program:

> b'{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/access_token]","status":403}

## The System and Versions

- Python 3.6.8
- requests 2.22.0
- requests-oauthlib 1.2.0
  Running everything through terminal.

## The Attempts

1. First of all the application settings have the correct permissions `r_liteprofile`.
2. I confirmed that I am authenticating with with correct scope.
3. I've tried adding various headers to the get request.
4. I console printed the contents of the PARAMETERS variable in the request object and found it to be an empty dict.

## The Code

I've added comments to explain which changes I've made from the stock tutorial on the requests-oauthlib website.

```py
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import linkedin_compliance_fix

# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = vault.CLIENT_ID
client_secret = vault.CLIENT_SECRET

# CHANGE: Scope is necessary to avoid permission errors
scope = ['r_liteprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'w_member_social']
redirect_url = 'http://127.0.0.1'

# OAuth endpoints given in the LinkedIn API documentation (you can check for the latest updates)
# CHANGE: updated urls
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'

# Authorized Redirect URL (from LinkedIn configuration)
# CHANGE: added scope argument to OAuth2Session init method
linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_url, scope=scope)
linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(linkedin)

# Redirect user to LinkedIn for authorization
authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
print('Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')

# Fetch the access token
# CHANGED: LinkedIn required client_id to be in body, flipped include_client_id to True
linkedin.fetch_token(token_url,client_secret=client_secret,
        include_client_id=True,authorization_response=redirect_response)

# CHANGED: Just an example of a header I tried passing to the get method below
headers = {'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'}
r = linkedin.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me')
print(r.content)
```

#### Any thoughts? Advice? Direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE 02/17/2020

As per the documentation and comments made on the github repository, https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib LinkedIn compliance fixes were outdated and causing bugs. The maintainers have since removed the LinkedIn compliance fix code and applied several updates to the LinkedIn example as part of [PR #397](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/pull/397). This should not be an issue anymore.

### Original Answer Below

Ultimately the request url I was passing contained an unpermitted field. Manual review of the url revealed two fields:

1. `oauth2_access_token`
2. `access_token`

Looking at the OAuth2-Requests source code, the second field is added to the url right before making the final request.

`requests-oauthlib/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py`

I imagine there is a mechanism in place to prevent the behavior but I could not find it and my comments/questions on their github and other places went unanswered. My solution was to copy a modified version of the `oauth2_session.py` module in my project with this  dirty fix within the `request()` method.

```
old_version_url = url
url, headers, data = self._client.add_token(url, http_method=method, body=data, headers=headers)
# Dirty work around to prevent the `access_token` parameter from being added
# to the url, causing a unpermitted parameters error requesting linkedin resource.
if "&access_token=" in url:
    url = old_version_url
```

The entire modified module can be found in this github repo, [linkedin_assist/linkedin_assist/quick_fixes/oauth2_session.py](https://github.com/jtroussard/linkedin_assist/blob/master/linkedin_assist/quick_fixes/oauth2_session.py)